# Heroku set default site

Tags: django, heroku

I have created a new Heroku site and I am developing it on my Linux box, using Django. The standard "getting started" site Heroku created for me is called "gettingstarted". How can I change that / configure Heroku to forget about it?

I was reading through the Django tutorial, which explains how to create a new site (`django-admin startproject my_site`). I did this successfully for a demo project. Then I tried to do it under the Heroku directory, because I wanted a better name for my site than "gettingstarted". I noticed that every time I start the Heroku server under my project, it says `...using settings 'gettingstarted.settings'`. I found that this is configured in `manage.py` and I change it.

This is the directory layout I have

```
/some/path/heroku_random_name/gettingstarted/settings.py
/some/path/heroku_random_name/my_site/settings.py
/some/path/heroku_random_name/my_app
```

This is what I have in

```
/some/path/heroku_random_name/manage.py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_site.settings')
```

so I would expect that the site that matters is `my_site`.

I got it to the point where I can run the site successfully on my local machine, and I can tell that it using the settings from `my_site`. But when I deploy the project to Heroku, it does not recognize `my_app` until I register it in `gettingstarted/settings.py`. In other words, when running in Heroku, it is still using `gettingstarted` as the site to run.

I am new to all this, so I left `gettingstarted` in the project, because I am afraid to break things. But how can I configure Heroku to execute settings from `my_site` and not from `gettingstarted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: it's configured in `Procfile`.

It's confusing because it's configured in one place for running locally and in a different place for running hosted at Heroku.